# Stop gulp pipeline from executing when jshint fails

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-jshint

I am using gulp to run a developer web server and I want the following tasks to happen when a change occurs to a javascript file:

- Lint javascript
- if there are no errors, copy files to .tmp/
- reload webpage

I've seen in other examples to use jshint.reporter('fail') as shown in the code below, to stop the rest of the pipeline.

```
var jshint   = require('gulp-jshint'),
    watch    = require('gulp-watch');

watch('resources/js/src/**/*.js', function() {
   util.log('Changes to js source files detected');
}).pipe(jshint())
.pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
.pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/js/src/'))
.pipe(connect.reload());
```

However when I do this it appears to always stop regardless of whether or not the lint was a success.  So, how can I end the pipeline after a failed linting?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works:

```
var map = require('map-stream');
...

var copyAndReload = map(function (file, cb) {
  if (file.jshint.success) {
    gulp.src('resources/js/src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/js/src/'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
    }
 });

watch('resources/js/src/**/*.js', function() {
  util.log('Changes to js source files detected');
}).pipe(jshint())
.pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
.pipe(copyAndReload);
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is plugin `plumber` to exit in case of error

so pipe the plumber in the linting process

```
    .pipe(plumber(_doExit))
```

here is how you defined _doExit

```
function _doExit() {
    process.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do that because I want the server to continue running.